# How to send multiple items to paypal using asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, vb.net, paypal

Hi I am using paypal sanbox to integrate asp.net website.I am able to send single item name to paypal.

But i don't know how i can send multiple items.I tried to search alot but did not get any specific answer.

Please let me know how i can send multiple parameters to paypal.

Here is my code:

```
Protected Sub imgbtn_Click(sender As Object, e As ImageClickEventArgs) Handles imgbtn.Click

Dim qty As Integer = Request.QueryString("qty")
Dim Amount As String = Request.QueryString("price")
Dim ItemDescription As String = Request.QueryString("ItemDescription")
Dim redirectUrl As String = ""

'Mention URL to redirect content to paypal site
redirectUrl += "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_xclick&business=" & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("paypalemail").ToString()

'Product Name
redirectUrl += "&item_name=" + ItemDescription

'Product Amount
redirectUrl += "&amount=" + Amount

'Business contact paypal EmailID
redirectUrl += "&xxxxx-facilitator@gmail.com"

'Quantiy of product, Here statically added quantity 1
redirectUrl += "&quantity=" + qty.ToString()

'If transactioin has been successfully performed, redirect SuccessURL page- this page will be designed by developer
redirectUrl += "&return=" & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("SuccessURL").Trim()"?item_name= & itemname


redirectUrl += "&cancel_return=" & ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("FailedURL").ToString()

Response.Redirect(redirectUrl)
```

This is code working for me to send single item to paypal.But i have  gridview with multiple items so how i can send multiple values to paypal.

Please suggest me.

Comment: Did you check on [Paypay-Api](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/)??

Comment: @huMptyduMpty  thanks for your reply.I cheked this.Can you provide me any sample,becuase i did not found any example for this.

Comment: It's been a while since I did any integration to PayPal but I believe when I did there was help on their site for this. I *think* you need to send your items in XML format if you want to send multiples.

Comment: @PeteEbdon   can you please provide me any example so i can get idea for this.

Comment: @sikha If I could remember I would. I looked up the link @humpty-dumpty provided and it looks like it's `JSON` now (although it was XML at one stage I'm sure). I was trying to integrate from a PHP shopping cart, so maybe the documentation was on there and not on the PayPal website.

Comment: Refer this link :
https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?cmd=_pdn_howto_checkout_outside

Comment: @NayeemMansoori link is not working.

Comment: please see below code its code working fine for my application and i hope it will helpfull for you.please try it.

Answer (score 0):

Found Answer no need to use

```
GridView.Rows.Count

just use a simple int to iterate 

int i = 0;
foreach(GridViewRow row in  temp_gridView.Rows)
{

box.Item_id = temp_gridView.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text;
box.Quantity = temp_gridView.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text;
box.Total = temp_gridView.Rows[i].Cells[2].Text;

i++;

}
```

Comment: looks it will work for me...one last question  how i can access item name in return url as i get single item..because i want to save these items in database.

Comment: But you are using multiple item send it to paypal so why you need to item_name in return url

Comment: becuase i want to save these items in database ,still now i haven't add these items into database.Items will add in database only when payment will confirm so thats the reason.

Comment: Ok when you redirect to paypal your application you are used in session to your list, if your transaction is on successfull then used the session list and save the each item which you buy in dataBase :likes used that 
 List<ShoppingCart> list = (List<ShoppingCart>)Session["lst"];

Comment: you understand that on not if you not please let me know

Comment: yes if it redirect to correct return url then we will save session value in dataabse right?

Comment: no, if your transaction is complete then we will save session value in database.

Comment: likes :
string Status = Request.QueryString["st"].ToString();
if(Status =="Completed") 
{
then we will save session value in database.

Comment: we will check this on success page.(st should be in redirect url) right?